# How to avoid access 'res' after getServerSideProps resolves?

Tags: javascript, next.js

In the page file of my nextJS application I do get the error

```
warn  - You should not access 'res' after getServerSideProps resolves.
Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/gssp-no-mutating-res
```

I did read the link, but I did not understand it. What does it mean `This object is not intended to be accessed or changed after getServerSideProps() resolves`.
For my understanding there is no *'after'*...

What am I doing wrong?

**[hash].tsx**

```
export const getServerSideProps: GetServerSideProps = async ({
  res,
  query: { hash }
}) => {
  if (!hash) return { notFound: true }

  try {
    const database = await mongodb()
    const Data = database.collection('data')

    const { fileId } = (await Data.findOne({ uid: hash })) || {}

    if (fileId) {
      const bucket = new GridFSBucket(database)
      const id = new ObjectId(fileId)
      const files: GridFSFile[] = await bucket.find({ _id: id }).toArray()
      const file = files[0]
      const { contentType, length } = file || {}

      res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': contentType })

      bucket
        .openDownloadStream(id)
        .on('data', (chunk) => {
          res.write(chunk)
        })
        .on('end', () => {
          res.end()
        })
    } else if (link) {
      return {
        redirect: {
          destination: link,
          permanent: false
        }
      }
    }

    return {
      props: {}
    }
  } catch (error) {
    if (error instanceof MongoServerError) {
      console.error(error)
    }
    throw error
  }
}

const HashPage: NextPage = () => {
  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <Head>
        <title>Title</title>
      </Head>
    </ThemeProvider>
  )
}

export default HashPage
```

**_document.tsx**

```
class Document extends NextDocument {
  render() {
    return (
      <Html>
        <Head>
          <meta httpEquiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />
          <meta charSet="utf-8" />
          <meta name="theme-color" content={theme.palette.primary.main} />
        </Head>
        <body style={{ backgroundColor: '#f2f2f2' }}>
          <Main />
          <NextScript />
        </body>
      </Html>
    )
  }
}

Document.getInitialProps = async (ctx) => {
  // Render app and page and get the context of the page with collected side effects.
  const sheets = new ServerStyleSheets()
  const originalRenderPage = ctx.renderPage

  ctx.renderPage = () =>
    originalRenderPage({
      enhanceApp: (App) => (props) => sheets.collect(<App {...props} />)
    })

  const initialProps = await NextDocument.getInitialProps(ctx)

  return {
    ...initialProps,
    id: ctx?.query?.id,
    // Styles fragment is rendered after the app and page rendering finish.
    styles: [
      ...React.Children.toArray(initialProps.styles),
      sheets.getStyleElement()
    ]
  }
}

export default Document
```

Answer (score 1):

In your code snippet, you're using res to handle the response directly within the getServerSideProps function. However, getServerSideProps is a special Next.js function that is used to fetch data and perform server-side rendering. The warning is telling you that once getServerSideProps has resolved and returned its result, you should not further manipulate the res object.

The reason for this is that Next.js has already started processing the HTTP response based on the data returned by getServerSideProps. Attempting to change the response after this point could lead to unpredictable behavior or errors.

To resolve this issue, you should restructure your code to handle any response-related logic within the return statement of getServerSideProps. In your case, you are using res to set the response headers and stream data from GridFS. You can move this logic to the return statement like this:

```
export const getServerSideProps: GetServerSideProps = async ({ res, query: { hash } }) => {
  if (!hash) return { notFound: true }

  try {
    const database = await mongodb()
    const Data = database.collection('data')

    const { fileId } = (await Data.findOne({ uid: hash })) || {}

    if (fileId) {
      const bucket = new GridFSBucket(database)
      const id = new ObjectId(fileId)
      const files: GridFSFile[] = await bucket.find({ _id: id }).toArray()
      const file = files[0]
      const { contentType, length } = file || {}

      res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': contentType })

      bucket
        .openDownloadStream(id)
        .on('data', (chunk) => {
          res.write(chunk)
        })
        .on('end', () => {
          res.end()
        })

      // You can return an empty object here since you've already handled the response.
      return { props: {} }
    } else if (link) {
      return {
        redirect: {
          destination: link,
          permanent: false
        }
      }
    }

    // If neither of the above conditions is met, you can return an empty object.
    return { props: {} }
  } catch (error) {
    if (error instanceof MongoServerError) {
      console.error(error)
    }
    throw error
  }
}
```

By making this change, you ensure that you only access and manipulate res within the appropriate context of getServerSideProps, avoiding the warning and potential issues.

Comment: If I do not misunderstand you, I just have to add a `return { props: {} }` right after `bucket.openDownloadStream(id)` to return an empty props. But with that the warning is still there. Did I miss something?

Comment: If you're still encountering the warning, it's possible that there may be another part of your code that's accessing res after it should not be accessed. Can you please share the complete code for your component and any other related code, such as middleware or any custom server configuration?